# how to refresh DataGridView after deleting a row form DataGridView and database in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

after deleting a selected row of stockdataGridView1, It don't refresh. please tell me how to refresh after deleting selected row. do I need to reopen the form or add another button for refresh ?

```
private void stockdataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

}

private void Report_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database = stock; integrated Security = true";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    string query = "SELECT * FROM stocktable1";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    List<Stock> stocks = new List<Stock>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.id = (int)reader["id"];
        stock.gsm = reader["gsm"].ToString();
        stock.color = reader["color"].ToString();
        stock.size = reader["size"].ToString();
        stock.yard = reader["yard"].ToString();
        stock.meter = reader["meter"].ToString();
        stock.quantity = reader["quantity"].ToString();
        stock.supplier = reader["supplier"].ToString();
        stock.purpose = reader["purpose"].ToString();
        stock.chalanno = reader["chalanno"].ToString();
        stocks.Add(stock);
    }
    reader.Close();
    connection.Close();
    stockdataGridView1.DataSource = stocks;
}

private void deletebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int id = (int)stockdataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["id"].Value;
    string connectionString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database = stock; integrated Security = true";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    string query = "delete from stocktable1 where id=" + id;
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    int rowaffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
    stockdataGridView1.Update();
    stockdataGridView1.Refresh();  

    MessageBox.Show("deleted");
}
```

}
    }

[image]

Comment: you need to call this method after you delete the row `Report_Load` if this is how you bind the data on the initial load.. how else do you expect the DataGrid to know what's been deleted..?

Comment: what should be the parameter of Report_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) method when I call this after deleting

Comment: make use of functions more often, your code contains repetitive static statement calls such establishing a connection, contain those statements  within a function and call the function saving you the hassle of re-writing those statemtens!

Comment: create a new "object" and a new "EventArgs" object, just give them names you don't have to give them values and pass them to the function call parameters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/9kkx3h3c.aspx however this is not the proper way and is a lazy approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the new method I have created below and adjust the original method as shown below, the method should get called when you load the grid and once you delete it.

As I mentioned within my comments, your code needs adjustment, use functions more odten.

```
        private void stockdataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpdateAndLoad()
        {

            string connectionString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database = stock; integrated Security = true";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string query = "SELECT * FROM stocktable1";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            List<Stock> stocks = new List<Stock>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Stock stock = new Stock();
                stock.id = (int)reader["id"];
                stock.gsm = reader["gsm"].ToString();
                stock.color = reader["color"].ToString();
                stock.size = reader["size"].ToString();
                stock.yard = reader["yard"].ToString();
                stock.meter = reader["meter"].ToString();
                stock.quantity = reader["quantity"].ToString();
                stock.supplier = reader["supplier"].ToString();
                stock.purpose = reader["purpose"].ToString();
                stock.chalanno = reader["chalanno"].ToString();
                stocks.Add(stock);
            }
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
            stockdataGridView1.DataSource = stocks;
        }

        private void Report_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateAndLoad();
        }

        private void deletebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int id = (int)stockdataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["id"].Value;
            string connectionString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database = stock; integrated Security = true";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string query = "delete from stocktable1 where id=" + id;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            int rowaffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            stockdataGridView1.Update();
            stockdataGridView1.Refresh();  

            MessageBox.Show("deleted");
            UpdateAndLoad();
        }
```

Comment: @anasbiswas the code is now updated! Your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the grid after rows are added or deleted you need to set the `DataSource` property of the grid again and then invoke `DataBind()` method on the `DataGridView` object. In your case, you can define the the data source i.e. your `List<Stock>` object at the class level and while capturing the click event of the Delete button, rebind the data source as explained previously, to the data grid view.